Excel cost calculations using rank function
I have a table showing the number of days different users will be using different apps. I need to assume the same start date for each user with the daily cost for the app being split equally accross the users still using it.
I've tried lots of methods like rank, index but can't make this work.
The below example shows my expected outcome. (Note: I have many more users/ apps in my actual table).
For example for app 4, all three users split the first 30 days (3000/3=1000), u1 and u2 split the next 60 days (6000/2=3000) and u1 pays for the final 60 days (6000).


Seems to me that you will need to use PowerQuery to unpivot and process the data.
First of all simplify your input table:

Load it into PowerQuery, unpivot and for every combination of app/user check if there are overlapping days from other users and calculate a bunch of things.  The code is very clunky and no doubt can be simplified and made better:
let
// Load data from the current workbook
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],


// Unpivot columns
UnpivotedColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"App", "Cost"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

// Function to create a list of values less than or equal to the given value for the given app
CreateLessThanList = (app as number, value as number, table as table) =>
    let
        FilteredTable = Table.SelectRows(table, each [App] = app and [Value] <= value),
        ValueList = List.Sort(FilteredTable[Value])
    in
        ValueList,

// Add a column with the list of values less than or equal to each value
AddLessThanList = Table.AddColumn(UnpivotedColumns, "LessThanList", each CreateLessThanList([App], [Value], UnpivotedColumns)),

// Expand the list column
ExpandedLessThanList = Table.ExpandListColumn(AddLessThanList, "LessThanList"),

// Sort the rows
SortedRows = Table.Sort(ExpandedLessThanList, {
    {"App", Order.Ascending},
    {"Attribute", Order.Ascending},
    {"LessThanList", Order.Descending}
}),

// Add index columns
AddedIndex0 = Table.AddIndexColumn(SortedRows, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
AddedIndex1 = Table.AddIndexColumn(SortedRows, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

// Merge queries to compare the current and previous rows
MergedQueries = Table.NestedJoin(
    AddedIndex0,
    {"App", "Attribute", "Index"},
    AddedIndex1,
    {"App", "Attribute", "Index"},
    "PreviousRow",
    JoinKind.LeftOuter
),

// Expand the merged table
ExpandedPreviousRow = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergedQueries, "PreviousRow", {"LessThanList"}, {"PreviousLessThanList"}),

// Calculate the custom column
AddedCustom = Table.AddColumn(ExpandedPreviousRow, "Custom", each if [PreviousLessThanList] is null then [LessThanList] else [LessThanList] - [PreviousLessThanList]),

// Remove duplicates and unnecessary columns
RemovedDuplicates = Table.Distinct(AddedCustom, {"App", "Attribute", "Value", "LessThanList"}),
RemovedColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(RemovedDuplicates, {"Index", "PreviousLessThanList"}),

// Add adjusted values column
AddedAdjusted = Table.AddColumn(RemovedColumns, "Adjusted", each if [Custom] = 0 then [LessThanList] else [Custom]),
CleanedColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(AddedAdjusted, {"Custom"}),

// Add a column to count occurrences of each LessThanList value
AddCustomColumn = Table.AddColumn(CleanedColumns, "Count", each List.Count(
    Table.Column(
        Table.SelectRows(CleanedColumns, (row) => row[App] = _[App] and row[LessThanList] = _[LessThanList]), 
        "App"
    )
)),

// Calculate user cost
AddedUserCost = Table.AddColumn(AddCustomColumn, "User cost", each (if [Adjusted] = 0 then [LessThanList] else [Adjusted]) / [Count] * [Cost]),

// Remove unnecessary columns
FinalColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(AddedUserCost, {"LessThanList", "Adjusted", "Count"}),

// Group rows by App and Attribute, summing the User cost
GroupedRows = Table.Group(FinalColumns, {"App", "Attribute"}, {{"User cost", each List.Sum([User cost]), type number}})
in
GroupedRows

Load the query back to Excel and you can now pivot the data again:


The cost per user per day is:
Daily cost / Number of users sharing that day

which gives for the total number of days' usage for a particular user:
=IF(B2=0,0,100*SUM(SEQUENCE(B2,1,1,0)/COUNTIF($B2:$D2,">="&SEQUENCE(B2))))


